# What is mechanism of action of ellagic acid as an antimicrobial compound?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, microbiology, organic-chemistry

Ellagic acid (a polyphenol) works as an antimicrobial compound. But what is its mechanism of action?

I found these 2 research papers related to this, however the mechanism of action is not clearly explained in either of them. Is there a paper that effectively explains the mechanism of action?

- [doi:10.3389/fmicb.2019.00829](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmicb.2019.00829/full)(in page 2, it is mentioned that the compounds are known to involve many sites of action at the cellular level, but why does it affect the site of action?)
- [doi:10.1002/chem.202000354](https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/chem.202000354) (In page 3, It has been postulated that ellagitannins inhibit the growth of microorganisms by sequestering metal ions critical for microbial growth, but direct bacterial targets remain unidentified.
  Is there a paper which explains why it inhibits growth more clearly?

Comment: What do you mean by mechanism of action? I would argue that those papers both present possible mechanisms of action related to cellular adhesion. Why does that not answer your question?

Comment: @MaximilianPress Indeed, in the first one, the entire second paragraph is entirely about this question; in the second one, *it's a picture within the abstract* - pretty rare to find a picture in an abstract, for sure, but certainly not hidden information. OP - can you clarify what is missing/where the gap is between these papers and what you want to know?

Comment: Thank you for editing, but I don't think you've adequately addressed the above comments and thus have voted to leave closed. For example, as noted by Bryan the abstract of the second paper you link shows a clear mechanism that you seem to be ignoring. ——— Also note that questions on this site work best if they are narrowly focused — an example would be asking why biofilm disruption is important for antimicrobial activity, or better yet how biofilms contribute to infections in *Streptococcus* (including a summary with references of what you've learned about the question from your research).